# How to remove sshfs directory on MacOS?

Tags: terminal, osx, sshfs, fuse

I am trying to use FUSE and SSHFS to mount a home directory from a cluster to my local machine (MacBook Pro with Sierra). Everything was fine until I updated to Sierra and now I am not able to use two scripts a professor gave me to mount and unmount the remote filesystem easily!
So I tried to do that by using

```
sshfs ics: ~/Desktop
```

I successfully did what I need to do but now on my Desktop there is this Desktop folder that I am not able to delete because if I try it says that it is necessary to MacOS.
What can I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to unmount the sshfs mount? Typically this is done using:

```
fusermount -u /path/to/mountpoint
```

Comment: The problem that this was a test and now I have the folder remaining there! I do not want it any more...